# How to get current screen details in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx-2, screen

I have multiple monitor connected with my PC. From javaFX I can get primary screen. But I need to know about the screen details of the screen the stage currently is. How can I get that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use [getScreensForRectangle](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Screen.html#getScreensForRectangle%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double%29) with the x, y, width and height of your window.